# ruby nokorigi export csv columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i want to export csv in 3 columns with the type of it but the result that i get is not the same what i want. it's just only one column to show all my data, please help me what should i do

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'csv'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("index.html"))

fullName = page.css('li._5i_q').css("a[data-gt]").children.map {|name| name.text }
shortURL = page.css('li._5i_q').css("._5j0e a[data-hovercard]")
myID = shortURL.map {|element|
  element["data-hovercard"][/id=([^&]*)/].gsub('id=', '')
}
messenger = shortURL.map {|element|
  element["data-hovercard"][/id=([^&]*)/].gsub('id=', '') + "@gmail.com"
}

attributes = %w{ID FullName Messenger}

CSV.open('chatId.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  csv << attributes

  myID.each do |x|
      csv << [x]
  end
  fullName.each do |y|
      csv << [y]
  end
  messenger.each do |z|
    csv << [z]
  end
end
```

It's all my code

Comment: can you explain what the expected output is, and what the output of your code is?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write row by row when exporting data to csv. Therefore, try to create an array of `[x, y, z]` and export them using `to_csv` method. For example:

```
data = myID.zip(fullName, shortUrl)

CSV.open('chatId.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  csv << attributes
  csv << "\n"
  data.each do |d|
    csv << d.to_csv
  end
end
```